# Typescript: First compile always fails but second succeds

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have an application than uses webpack and typescript. As I stated in the title: when I run `npm run dev` it fails. But when I save any file without changing anything it compiles successfully.

What could be causing this behavior?

This is the output of `npm run dev`

```
> parques-a-la-colombiana@1.0.0 dev /home/alejo/playground/parquesFrontend
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --mode=development --inline --hot

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from undefined
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/alejo/playground/parquesFrontend
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to index.html
(node:54791) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_ASSETS] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.assets will be frozen in future, all modifications are deprecated.
BREAKING CHANGE: No more changes should happen to Compilation.assets after sealing the Compilation.
    Do changes to assets earlier, e. g. in Compilation.hooks.processAssets.
    Make sure to select an appropriate stage from Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_*.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
✖ ｢wdm｣: assets by chunk 6.41 MiB (name: main)
  asset main.css 3.22 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset bundle.js 3.19 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset 774544e6c2545bbb452c642d117f08a7.png 196 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: assets/t4p.png] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 344 bytes [emitted]
Entrypoint main 6.41 MiB (196 KiB) = main.css 3.22 MiB bundle.js 3.19 MiB 1 auxiliary asset
runtime modules 27.3 KiB 14 modules
modules by path ./src/ 320 KiB (javascript) 2.38 MiB (css/mini-extract)
  modules by path ./src/Pages/*.vue 287 KiB 49 modules
  modules by path ./src/*.ts 29 KiB 7 modules
  modules by path ./src/*.vue 1.88 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./src/Components/*.vue 2.61 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./src/*.css 359 bytes (javascript) 2.38 MiB (css/mini-extract) 2 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 823 KiB 31 modules
./assets/t4p.png 80 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in /home/alejo/playground/parquesFrontend/src/Pages/JuegoPruebas.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/alejo/playground/parquesFrontend/src/Pages/JuegoPruebas.vue.ts(3,8)
      TS1259: Module '"*.png"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 1 error in 16377 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

And after saving any file:

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: assets by status 3.41 MiB [cached] 2 assets
assets by path . 3.2 MiB
  asset bundle.js 3.19 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset main.2aaf46a0f4b3d8b61d55.hot-update.js 10.9 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset 2aaf46a0f4b3d8b61d55.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]
Entrypoint main 6.42 MiB (196 KiB) = main.css 3.22 MiB bundle.js 3.19 MiB main.2aaf46a0f4b3d8b61d55.hot-update.js 10.9 KiB 1 auxiliary asset
cached modules 1.11 MiB (javascript) 2.38 MiB (css/mini-extract) [cached] 104 modules
runtime modules 27.3 KiB 14 modules
cacheable modules 4.61 KiB
  code generated modules 2.09 KiB [code generated]
    ./src/routes.ts 1.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].use[0]!./src/Pages/Juego.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 953 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/Pages/Juego.vue 604 bytes [built]
  ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].use[0]!./src/Pages/Juego.vue?vue&type=template&id=98cb5c64&bindings={} 1.93 KiB [built]
webpack 5.4.0 compiled successfully in 5530 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Here it is the package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "parques-a-la-colombiana",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --mode=development --inline --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production --progress",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=testing jest --watchAll --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "find . -path ./node_modules -prune -o -path ./generadores/templates -prune -o -path ./build -prune -o -type f \\( -iname \\*.js -o -iname \\*\\.ts \\) -print | xargs -I{} npx eslint {}",
    "lint:fix": "find . -path ./node_modules -prune -o -path ./generadores/templates -prune -o -path ./build -prune -o -type f \\( -iname \\*.js -o -iname \\*\\.ts \\) -print | xargs -I{} npx eslint --fix {}"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/alejomongua/parquesFrontend.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.1.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.9.6",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.9",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^16.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^7.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

And my webpack configuration file:

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: ENV,
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ],
              }
            },
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: '[path][base].br',
      algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
      test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
      deleteOriginalAssets: false,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to really pinpoint but it looks like a `webpack5` related issue. From what I know, quite a few packages are not fully compatible with `webpack5`. Try downgrading to `webpack4` and downgrading the related packages to a lower version.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was in the same error message:

I had to add the option `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to the `tsconfig.json` file

This allows to import png file and now the error is gone

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I hope this information is useful to someone.